# What data should I (can I) gather to prove a .net bug in third party software?

Tags: .net-4.0

Our users are using a third-party system and every so often - a user might go all day without this happening, other days they may see it two or three times in seven hours - a red x will appear on screen rather than a button, field, or control.

This is not accompanied by an error message - at least not a message that appears on the screen to the user. It's simply a red x - as large as the control (so sometimes almost the entire screen, sometimes just the size of a 25-character field).

This is a .net system.

Looking online I can see that this is a .net error. Problem is, our devs didn't write it, and the vendor wants proof that the problem resides with their system, not our PCs.

What can we do to gather information on such an issue that would allow us to make our case to the vendor and get them to create a fix? I'm thinking of data to gather - anything from OS, memory. .net version installed etc.

But I'd also like to know about error logging - I'm sure it's possible to log errors that occur in third-party systems, but how do I do that?

Comment: Please include the error message, what sort of application it is.  As it stands right now no one can answer this question definitively.  The Windows Event Viewer should have information about the error. Also, expand your question to more than just 'Is it possible to log errors' the answer that question is a "yes" (as long as their application doesn't catch all exceptions), but I'm sure you want to know *how*.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I would take a look in the Application Log in the event viewer for any exception logs that relate to the application.

If the vendor is asking you for proof, I would ask the vendor how to go about gathering it. Their application may have a debug mode or a log file that could be used to assist in debugging the problem, however the vendor is best placed to advise you on this.